# switch case being used in a do{}while statement causes the GoAgain to not work properly

Tags: c++, do-while

The following code when run fails to activate the commands in the switch statement as well as prevents the GoAgain at the end of the } while to not work correctly in asking the user if they want to exit before it does so. The GoAgain() Function works correctly by itself and even when called in others. I also tried having it run the addition outside of the case(even though I clearly need to fix the math) and it runs. However as soon as it tries to run the switch statement it sets the GoAgain as false and terminates. Help!

```
// Fractions Project.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//  =================
    struct Fraction {

        int num;
        int den;
};  // Structure Fraction
//  =====================

//  ==================
//  Funtion Prototypes
//  =================================
    Fraction Add(Fraction, Fraction);
    Fraction Multiply(Fraction, Fraction);
    Fraction Subtract(Fraction, Fraction);
    Fraction Divide(Fraction, Fraction);
    void     PrintFraction(string, Fraction);
    void     SetFraction(Fraction&);
    bool     GoAgain();
//  ================================

//  ============
    int main() {

        do {

            int choice;
            Fraction fA, fB, fC;
            SetFraction(fA);
            SetFraction(fB);
            PrintFraction("fA", fA);
            PrintFraction("fB", fB);
            Add(fA, fB);
            PrintFraction("fA", fA);
            PrintFraction("fB", fB);

            fC = Add(fA, fB);

            PrintFraction("fA + fB ", fC);

                cout << endl << endl << "Table of Operations" << endl;
                cout << "A -- Addition" << endl;
                cout << "B -- Subtraction" << endl;
                cout << "C -- Multiplication" << endl;
                cout << "D -- Division" << endl << endl;
                cout << "Enter choice for calculation: ";
                cin >> choice;

                switch (choice) // Switch function allows user to choose the calculation to execute
                {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                {
                    Add(fA, fB);
                    PrintFraction("fA", fA);
                    PrintFraction("fB", fB);

                    fC = Add(fA, fB);

                    PrintFraction("fA + fB ", fC);

                }

                    break;
                case 'B':
                case 'b': Subtract(fA, fB);
                    PrintFraction("fA", fA);
                    PrintFraction("fB", fB);

                    fC = Subtract(fA, fB);

                    PrintFraction("fA - fB ", fC);

                    GoAgain();

                    break;
                case 'C':
                case 'c': Multiply(fA, fB);
                    PrintFraction("fA", fA);
                    PrintFraction("fB", fB);

                    fC = Multiply(fA, fB);

                    PrintFraction("fA x fB ", fC);

                    GoAgain();

                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'd': Divide(fA, fB);
                    PrintFraction("fA", fA);
                    PrintFraction("fB", fB);

                    fC = Divide(fA, fB);

                    PrintFraction("fA / fB ", fC);

                    GoAgain();

                    break;
                }
        } while (GoAgain());



        return 0;
    }// Function main()
//  ===================

//  ========================================
    Fraction Add(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {

        int a = f1.num, b = f1.den;
        int c = f2.num, d = f2.den;
        Fraction fSum;

        fSum.num = a*d + b*c;
        fSum.den = b*d;

        return fSum;


    }// Function Add()
//  ==================

//  ===========================================================
    void PrintFraction(string fractionname, Fraction fraction) {

        cout << fractionname << " = ";
        cout << fraction.num << "/" << fraction.den << endl;

    }// Function PrintFraction()
//  ============================

//  ======================================
    void SetFraction(Fraction& fraction) {

        cout << "Enter a value for the numerator please ==> ";
        cin >> fraction.num;

        do {
            cout << "Enter a value for the denominator please ==> ";
            cin >> fraction.den;

            if (fraction.den == 0){
                cout << "The denominator cannot be zero. " << endl;
                cout << "Enter a nonzero denominator." << endl;
            } // then
        } while (fraction.den == 0);
    }// Function SetFraction()
//  ==========================

//  ========================================
    Fraction Multiply(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {

        int a = f1.num, b = f1.den;
        int c = f2.num, d = f2.den;
        Fraction fSum;

        fSum.num = a*d;
        fSum.den = b*c;

        return fSum;


    }// Function Multiply()
//  =======================

//  ===============
    bool GoAgain(){
//  ===============
        char answer;

        cout << endl << "Would you like to try again? (y/n)";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;
        if (answer == 'y' | answer == 'Y')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }// Function GoAgain()
//  ======================

//  =============================================
    Fraction Subtract(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {

        int a = f1.num, b = f1.den;
        int c = f2.num, d = f2.den;
        Fraction fSum;

        fSum.num = a*d - b*c;
        fSum.den = b*d;

        return fSum;


    }// Function Subtract()
//  =======================

//  ===========================================
    Fraction Divide(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {

        int a = f1.num, b = f1.den;
        int c = f2.num, d = f2.den;
        Fraction fSum;

        fSum.num = (a*d) / (b*c);
        fSum.den = b*d;

        return fSum;


    }// Function Divide()
//  =====================
```

Comment: You're calling `GoAgain()` as the last step in most of the `switch`'s `case`s, but then in the `do`-`while` condition: it should be only the latter, as the `true`/`false` value's then determines whether the loop continues, as clearly intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `choice` is an integer, you treat it as a character.

That mean when you do

```
cin >> choice
```

then the input function expects an integer, and when it sees something which is not an integer then it will fail, and set `choice` to zero.

If you want to read a character, then `choice` have to be a `char`. Do note that this will lead to other problems, as then `cin >> choice` will read only a single character, and leave the newline in the input buffer, and you need to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the line.

You should also add a `default` case to your `switch` statement, to detect when the user inputs something which you did not expect.

You should also not call `GoAgain` in the cases.

Comment: *"leave the newline in the input buffer, and you need to `ignore` the rest of the line"* - it doesn't have to be ignored if you're using `>>` for the next input operations, and skipping whitespace again anyway, though it's certainly worth consideration to keep the code "clean".

Comment: Thank you I was so focused on the failed switch I didn't realize that it was an incorrect type. I am curious as to why GoAgain failed to run properly however. Shouldn't have still runn the GoAgain since with the failure of the switch it should have run on till the do while loop ended.

Comment: Reapeating GoAgain at the end of each case was part of my efforts to identify what was wrong with the switch. After changing the choice from int to char the code ran as intended thus showing the extra GoAgains to be redundant.